# UE4 Failed to find animation class during project packaging

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

In the player class constructor, I use ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder to get a link to blueprint animation class:

```
static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UAnimBlueprint> finderAnim(TEXT("AnimBlueprint'/Game/MixamoAnimPack/Mixamo_Adam/Anims/MixamoAnimBP_Adam.MixamoAnimBP_Adam'"));
```

Then I call SetAnimClass() method:

```
if (finderAnim.Succeeded())
    PlayerMesh->SetAnimClass(finderAnim.Object->GetAnimBlueprintGeneratedClass());
```

Everything works in the UE4 editor, but when I started packing the project, something went wrong and I got an error:

```
> PackagingResults: Warning: Error: CDO Constructor (Enemy): Failed to find /Game/MixamoAnimPack/Mixamo_Mortimer/Anims/MixamoAnimBP_Mortimer.MixamoAnimBP_Mortimer
```

Is there a solution to this problem or I should create a blueprint class of the player and choose the animation there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/1342624-cdo-constructor-failed-to-find-thirdperson-c-template-mannequin-animbp) is a similar question on Unreal Engine's Forum.

This is the proposed solution:

> Adding "_C" at the end of filename and treating the file as a "UClass"
>   makes things run smoother. Now it runs properly on both editor and
>   packaged game.

So your initialization of `finderAnim` will look like:

```
static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UClass> finderAnim(TEXT("AnimBlueprint'/Game/MixamoAnimPack/Mixamo_Adam/Anims/MixamoAnimBP_Adam.MixamoAnimBP_Adam_C'"));
```

PS: Go through JamesG's (Lead Programmer - UE4 Animation/Physics/Audio Team) answer on [this](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/2721-failed-to-find-path-to-object) thread to understand it more clearly.

Comment: Thank you, it's working great. It's weird that I didn't stumble across an existing solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibly more robust solution is to use `FClassFinder`.

```
static ConstructorHelpers::FClassFinder<UAnimInstance> finderAnim(TEXT("/Game/MixamoAnimPack/Mixamo_Adam/Anims/MixamoAnimBP_Adam"));
```

after which you can simply

```
PlayerMesh->SetAnimClass(finderAnim.Class);
```